# ArrayList не добавляет Parcelable

Tags: android

```
 public class ParcelObject implements Parcelable{

    public String paramOne;
    public String paramToo;

    public ParcelObject(String paramOne, String paramToo )
    {
        this.paramOne = paramOne;
        this.paramToo = paramToo;

    }

    private ParcelObject(Parcel parcel)
    {
        paramOne = parcel.readString();
        paramToo = parcel.readString();

    }

    public static final Creator<ParcelObject> CREATOR = new Creator<ParcelObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public ParcelObject createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ParcelObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ParcelObject[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ParcelObject[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(paramOne);
        dest.writeString(paramToo);

    }
}
```

И при попытке в `MainActivity` добавить `Parcelable` в `ArrayList` ничего не происходит. Не добавляется.

```
ArrayList<ParcelObject > arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
ParcelObject c = new ParcelObject ("Name","Title");
arraylist .add(c);
```

ArrayList остается пустым.

Comment: А как вы выясняете что он пуст?

Comment: В нем содержится одно значение. Прошёл отладчиком. Это значение как раз и есть добавленный Parcelable, которой и содержит две строки. Вопрос теперь в том, как их достать при получении.

    ArrayList<ParcelObject> myList;
    myList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("MT");


Так получаю сам ArrayList c Parcelable. А как добраться до его значений?

Comment: Э-э-э... myList.get(0)?

Comment: Вы серьезно? вы можете получить array из arguments, но для вас проблема получать значения из array?

Comment: Вот не мог подумать что можно было вот так сделать.

            ParcelObject obg = myList.get(0);
          
Спасибо, Юрий.
Я  так и получал,Но не знал что дальше с ним делать.
А точнее не мог даже предположить что такая вот конструкция пройдет.